# Need to insert a string in a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table having data in the following format .I am using oracle 10g

SR/0001

I want to replace it with
SR/MMM/0001

I used replace string but it is not working,

Comment: You need to tell us more about the problem. Does the input string always have exactly one forward slash in it? Where does the **additional** string come from? Does it need to come right after the slash, and be followed by one more slash?

Comment: exact format is SR/0001/18-19. Iwant to insert an additional string SR/MMM/0001/18-19

Comment: No need  got the answer SELECT REPLACE(srno, 'SR/', 'SR/CSG/') from my_table

Comment: This means that all your strings begin with `SR/` - you can't have, for example, `ST/0001/18-19` in your data. Is **any** part of your input string variable?

Answer (score 2):

if you just need a replace of the '/' char in the middle of the string you can  test  the result this way

```
select replace('SR/0001', '/' , '/MMM/') from dual; 

select replace(your_col,  '/' , '/MMM/') from your_table
```

and if you want update you value in the table then you could use

```
 update your_table 
 set your_col = replace(your_col,  '/' , '/MMM/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input has exactly one forward slash, and the additional string is given as a bind variable that must come right after the slash, and must be followed by an additional slash:

```
with
  inputs(str) as (
    select 'SR/0001' from dual union all
    select 'SR/0004' from dual
  )
select str, replace(str, '/', '/' || :p_additional_str || '/') as new_str
from   inputs
;

STR     NEW_STR
------- -----------
SR/0001 SR/MMM/0001
SR/0004 SR/MMM/0004
```

(after assigning 'MMM' to the bind variable, of course).

**EDIT**

If the input string is longer, it has more than one slash, and the added string must be after the first slash, use REGEXP_REPLACE, which allows you to show which slash to replace:

```
with
  inputs(str) as (
    select 'SR/0001/18-19' from dual union all
    select 'SR/0004/18-19' from dual
  )
select str, replace(str, '/', '/' || :p_additional_str || '/') as new_str
from   inputs
;

STR           NEW_STR
------------- ---------------------
SR/0001/18-19 SR/MMM/0001/MMM/18-19
SR/0004/18-19 SR/MMM/0004/MMM/18-19
```

This can be made more efficient using `INSTR/SUBSTR` and the like, but perhaps for your needs `REGEXP_REPLACE` will be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE` doesn't work? Does for me.

```
SQL> create table test (seq varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 'SR/0001' from dual union all
  3    select 'SR/0002' from dual union all
  4    select 'SR/0003' from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> update test set seq = replace(seq, 'SR/', 'SR/MMM/');

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * From test;

SEQ
--------------------
SR/MMM/0001
SR/MMM/0002
SR/MMM/0003

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
create table abc select * from yourtable;
delete from yourtable;
insert into yourtable select regexp_replace(col1,'/','/MMM/') from abc;
```